# How do we check if a element does not exist in Tcl list?

Tags: tcl

I know we can use `in` to check if list element exist in a Tcl list.

Is there another way to check if the list element does not exist in a Tcl list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`in` operator https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/In

`ni` operator https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/ni

In TCL we have both `in` and `ni` operators, `ni` is the answer to your question. Check the links above.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a sorted list, you can use [`lsearch -sorted`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/lsearch.html#M9) to do a binary search, which can be more efficient than `in` or `ni` on long lists.

```
set lst {1 2 3 4 5 6 8 9}
puts [expr {[lsearch -sorted -integer $lst 6] > -1}] ;# true if present
puts [expr {[lsearch -sorted -integer $lst 7] > -1}] ;# false if not present
```

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to maintain the haystack values using a dict (as dictionary keys), then `dict exists` is also an interesting alternative:

```
set d [dict create 1 a 2 b 3 c 4 d 5 e 6 f]
dict exists $d 6; # in
expr {![dict exists $d 10]}; # ni
```

Note that only transforming a list into a dictionary, and vice versa, for the single task of checking for inclusion, exclusion would not pay off.